# Access variable in parent scope

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access the selectItems array from inside the functions in selectable object, but not sure if there is a way to do this without passing the _Multiselect object back into the function as a parameter.  Are there other ways?

```
function _MultiSelect() {
}
_MultiSelect.prototype = {

    selectedItems: [],

    selectable: {

        myFunc: function(){
            //how can I access selectedItems from here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does selectedItems has to be a part of the prototype ?

Comment: @marvel308 I'm not sure, I don't think I need to create new instance of multiselect object anywhere - its going to be a singleton so only one instance exists always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make `selectable` a function that returns an object containing `myFunc` and whatever else. This allows you to capture the `_MultiSelect` context in a closure and use it in the methods you are exposing.

```
_MultiSelect.prototype = {

    selectedItems: [],

    selectable: function() {
       var context = this;
       return {
          myFunc: function(){
            console.log(context.selectedItems);
            //how can I access selectedItems from here
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Usecase:

```
(new _MultiSelect).selectable().myFunc();
```

Comment: ok thanks, I was thinking to do this one - so that's the only way to capture the context of the parent object, by using a function?  Only function have this ability?

Comment: It's not the only way, but it is the easiest way if you want `selectedItems` to not be a static attribute. Objects have their own context (`this`), so whenever you nest them, a new context is created.

Answer (score 1):

you can store the context of this in that refer to the following code

```
    _MultiSelect.prototype = {

    selectedItems: [],

    selectable: function() {
        // store the context of this in that
       var that = this;
       return {
          myFunc: function(){
            // is accessible
            console.log(that.selectedItems);
          }
       }
    }
}
```